# How can I avoid logging into SalesForce databases on every router in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, salesforce

I need to do this to log into SalesForce Databases and pass a query. Now I will be passing a lot of queries on many routers of express.js and its a real pain to login in every router. Please let me know if you know how I can avoid this.

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  oauth2 : salesforce_credential.oauth2
});

var username = salesforce_credential.username;
var password = salesforce_credential.password;

// I want to avoid this login on every router
conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  conn.query("SELECT id FROM Sourcing__c WHERE id = 'req.session.ref'",function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }

    if(result.records.length === 0){
      req.session.ref = "";
    }
    var body = {
      "Auth__c": req.user.id,
      "Stus__c": "Pending - New Hire",
      "Record": "012lvIAC",
      "Sourcing__c": req.session.ref
    };
    conn.sobject("SFDC_Employee__c").create(body, function(err, ret) {
      if (err || !ret.success) {
        return console.error(err, ret);
      }
      console.log("Created record id : " + ret.id);
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may save the login status and check it every time when do a query,
here I add a property on conn (the instance of 'jsforce.Connection'), I'm not sure but I think there may be a method or property that show the login status of the 'conn', you may dig into its documents.

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  oauth2 : salesforce_credential.oauth2
});

var username = salesforce_credential.username;
var password = salesforce_credential.password;
conn._isLogin = false;

// here in your route handler
if (!conn._isLogin) {
  conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    conn._isLogin = true;
    doQuery(conn);
  });  
} else {
  doQuery(conn);
}

function doQuery (conn) {
  conn.query("SELECT id FROM Sourcing__c WHERE id = 'req.session.ref'",function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }

    if(result.records.length === 0){
      req.session.ref = "";
    }
    var body = {
      "Auth__c": req.user.id,
      "Stus__c": "Pending - New Hire",
      "Record": "012lvIAC",
      "Sourcing__c": req.session.ref
    };
    conn.sobject("SFDC_Employee__c").create(body, function(err, ret) {
      if (err || !ret.success) {
        return console.error(err, ret);
      }
      console.log("Created record id : " + ret.id);
      // ...
    });
  });
}
```